# File Input and output method issues

Tags: java

So my program is supposed to say what type of a token it is from my input file. My second method is supposed to write whatever input from the keyboard to an output file until the user types stop. The problem is my first method won't output the integers to their right type. My second method will only put stop in the output file. Here is my code. Any help would be much appriciated.

```
public class R16 {
public void readFile(String inputFile) {

    try {
        File in = new File(inputFile);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Integer: " + scan.nextInt());
            }
            if (scan.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println("String: " + scan.next());
            }

            if (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("Double: " + scan.nextDouble());
            }

        }

        scan.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error, not good");

    }

}

public void writeFile(String outputFile) {
    try {
        File out = new File(outputFile);
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(out);
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Text: ");
        while(!scan.next().equals("stop")){
            w.print(scan.next());

        }








        w.close();
        scan.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error, it just got real");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    R16 test = new R16();
    test.readFile(args[0]);
    test.writeFile(args[1]);

}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you should make the second two `if` statements into `else if` statements, and perhaps you should check `hasNextDouble()` before `hasNext()`. Actually, that would make `hasNext()` last, and redundant, since you already checked that in `while` loop, so a simple `else` would suffice.

Comment: it works thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, you check for `stop` then throw away all input.

```
while(!scan.next().equals("stop")){
```

Try using something like

```
String input;
while (!(input = scan.next()).equals("stop")) {
    w.print(input);
```

Now within the loop, you have access to the *input* variable which contains the input string.

Comment: `next()` does not return a "line".

Comment: Meh, line, input. Close enough.